# How to convert ones' complement number into its 2's complement?

Tags: java, string

> Given:A binary number in the form of String.Convert this into its 2's complement form

Example:

Input:

00000101

Output:

11111011

I know how to convert a binary number into its 1's compliment form. But I am unable to convert into 2 complement form.

For Example:

GivenString :111

1s Compliment 000

How to code1: Adding '1' to the 1's complement and 1+1=1?

MyCodeFor 1s Compliment:

```
        public static String complimentDecimal(String strnew)

        {


           //Replace the 0s with 1s and 1s with 0s
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          for(int j=0;j<strnew.length();j++)
          {
              if(strnew.charAt(j)=='0') 
                  sb.append("1");
              else if(strnew.charAt(j)=='1') 
                  sb.append("0");
          }
          String s1 = sb.toString();

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 2s compliment form?

Comment: Two's complement is a signed number representation obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the one's compliment to decimal form using `Integer.parseInt(<String value>, 2)`
You will get decimal form of the binary number. Add one to it and convert the number back to binary.

```
public static String complimentDecimal(String strnew)
{
    int s2=Integer.parseInt(strnew,2);
    if (s2==0)
    {
        String s4="1";
        for(int j=0;j<strnew.length();j++)
        {
            s4+="0";
        }
        return s4;
    }
    else{
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          for(int j=0;j<strnew.length();j++)
          {
              if(strnew.charAt(j)=='0') 
                  sb.append("1");
              else if(strnew.charAt(j)=='1') 
                  sb.append("0");
          }
          String s1 = sb.toString();
          int s = Integer.parseInt(s1, 2);//parse int radix = 2 for binary
          s++; //increment by one
        return Integer.toBinaryString(s);
    }
}
```

This will work for zero's.

Comment: This code doesn't work for 0. It breaks, because it is not considering cases in which overflow has to be ignored.

Comment: yeah, but in generall this is the shortest way to achive the op request

Comment: Yeah. I agree. I tried the same. I deleted my ans when came across this case.

Comment: same here, that was nice to solve and little bit tricky question : )

Comment: @sudheeshshetty  1011000011 IS your output correct for this? Correct output 0100111101.What you are getting.

Comment: @Jasonarora .Gettign value 100111101. This is the right answer right? You want that 0 too? The value remains the same.

Comment: Okay. So you wanted the zero's. Appending zero's and getting the result properly right. cool :)