# How to get 2's complement of a binary number in Java programmatically

Tags: java, binary, twos-complement

How to calculate the 2's Complement of a Hex number in Android/Java.

```
    For Example : 
    String x = 10011010;
    1's complement of x = 01100101;
    2's complement is 01100110;
```

*How I can pro-grammatically achieve in Java?*

I had tried the following code to convert the binary to its 1's compliment:

```
public String complementFunction(String bin) {
        String  ones = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < bin.length(); i++) {
            ones += flip(bin.charAt(i));
        }
        return ones;
    }

// Returns '0' for '1' and '1' for '0'
    public char flip(char c) {
        return (c == '0') ? '1' : '0';
    }
```

But I'm not able to get its two's complement.

Comment: Do you know the theory behind it? If you know the theory, implementing it is an easy task. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This possibly pure Java.. How is it specific to Android?

Comment: @BackSlash I have posted my code to get 1's complement.

Comment: @suraj Android uses core Java itself.

Comment: You are right. my point was being a core java question, there is no need for android tag. It is not an android related issue

Comment: okay thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert ones' complement number into its 2's complement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196967/how-to-convert-ones-complement-number-into-its-2s-complement)

Comment: It's "complement", not "compliment". One should spell the terms of art correctly.

Comment: @Lew Bloch Sorry for misspell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your help everyone.
I got the solution and it is as follows :

```
  public String twosCompliment(String bin) {
        String twos = "", ones = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < bin.length(); i++) {
            ones += flip(bin.charAt(i));
        }
        int number0 = Integer.parseInt(ones, 2);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(ones);
        boolean b = false;
        for (int i = ones.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            if (ones.charAt(i) == '1') {
                builder.setCharAt(i, '0');
            } else {
                builder.setCharAt(i, '1');
                b = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!b)
            builder.append("1", 0, 7);

        twos = builder.toString();

        return twos;
    }

// Returns '0' for '1' and '1' for '0'
    public char flip(char c) {
        return (c == '0') ? '1' : '0';
    }
```

Thanks to all for helping.

Answer (score 2):

[This wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#From_the_ones.27_complement) explains an easy way to get the 2's complement: Get the 1's complement, then add 1 (in binary logic). So you can use the `complementFunction` you already have, then go through the String backwards. If you find a 1, flip it and continue. If you find a 0, flip it and stop.

```
String  twos = "";
for (int i = bin.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (bin.charAt(i) == '1') {
        twos = "0" + twos;
    } else {
        twos = bin.substring(0, i) + "1" + two;
        break;
    }
    twos = flip(bin.charAt(i));
}
return twos;
```

Comment: Also, without finding the 1's complement first: go through the original binary string backwards, if you find a 1 flip all other numbers after that 1.

Comment: @BackSlash - I think this comment is a saver.  Can you please explain the math behind this?

Comment: @BhanuDevapatla It's simple logic :) 2's complement is: `NOT(original) + 01`. So, for `0001`, it is `NOT(0001) + 01 = 1110 + 01 = 1111`. For `0010` it's `NOT(0010) + 01 = 1101 + 01 = 1110`. For `0011` it's `NOT(0011) + 01 = 1100 + 01 = 1101`. For `1111` it's `NOT(1111) + 01 = 0000 + 01 = 0001`. If you watch closely you'll notice that this is the same of 1) reading the number from right to left, 2) keeping the bits until you find a `1`, 3) negating all other bits (`0` becomes `1`, `1` becomes `0`).

Answer (score 1):

I was doing some browsing on this subject and ended up reading this question and its answers. The way I see it, there is this much simpler way to calculate the two's complement of a integer.

```
public static int twosComplement(final int value) {
    final int mask = 0xffff_ffff;
    return (value ^ mask) + 1;
}

public static String stringTwosComplement(String bin) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(bin, 2);
    int result = twosComplement(value);
    return Integer.toBinaryString(result);
}
```

The algorithm is based on the same idea @malte-hartwig brought in his answer: the two's complement is the **one's complement** plus `1`.

Answer (score 0):

@BackSlash's comment above is intriguing.  This answer is the full program written based on this idea:

```
import java.time.temporal.ValueRange;
import java.util.Scanner;

//This program generates convert decimal to binary
public class ConvertDecimalToBinary {


    public static int getNumberOfBytes(int n) {
        int bytes = 0;
        ValueRange byteRange = ValueRange.of(Byte.MIN_VALUE, Byte.MAX_VALUE);
        ValueRange shortRange = ValueRange.of(Short.MIN_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE);
        ValueRange intRange = ValueRange.of(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        if (byteRange.isValidValue(n)) {
            bytes = 1;
        } else if (shortRange.isValidValue(n)) {
            bytes = 2;
        } else if (intRange.isValidValue(n)) {
            bytes = 4;
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    //Convert a positive decimal number to binary
    public static String convertPositiveNumberToBinary(int n, int bytes,boolean reverse) {
        int bits = 8 * bytes;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bits); //in-bits
        if (n == 0) {
            sb.append("0");
        } else {
            while (n > 0) {
                sb.append(n % 2);
                n >>= 1;  //aka n/2
            }
        }

        if (sb.length() < bits) {
            for (int i = sb.length(); i < bits; i++) {
                sb.append("0");

            }
        }
        if (reverse) {
            return sb.toString();
        } else {
            return sb.reverse().toString();
        }
    }

    //Convert negative decimal number to binary
    public static String convertNegativeNumberToBinary(int n, int bytes) {
        int m = -n; //conver to positve
        String binary = convertPositiveNumberToBinary(m,bytes,true);
        int len = binary.length();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len); //in-bits
        boolean foundFirstOne = false;
        for(int i=0; i < len;i++) {
            if(foundFirstOne)  {
                if(binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
                    sb.append('0');
                }
                else {
                    sb.append('1');
                }
            }
            else {
                if(binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
                    foundFirstOne = true;
                }
                sb.append(binary.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return sb.reverse().toString();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int n = scanner.nextInt();
            int bytes = getNumberOfBytes(n);
            String binary;

            if(n >= 0) {
                binary = convertPositiveNumberToBinary(n,bytes,false);
            }
            else {
                binary = convertNegativeNumberToBinary(n,bytes);
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("Binary representation of {%s} is {%s}",n,binary));
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```